# Product of subgroups of a unipotent algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

As the title suggests, the question is about products of subgroups of a unipotent algebraic group. I will work with max-spec for algebraic groups over fields, and given an algebraic group $G$, by writing $g\in G$ I will mean $g$ is a point of the underlying set of $G$.

Let $G$ be a unipotent algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. Let $H$ and $K$ be algebraic subgroups of $G$ (over $k$). By Kostant-Rosenlicht theorem,
$$HK := \{hk : h\in H, k\in K\}$$
is a closed subset of $G$. Let $(HK)_a$ be the closed subvariety of $G$ with underlying set $HK$. We have
$$(HK)_a(k) = H(k)K(k).$$
My question is about $R$-valued points for an arbitrary commutative $k$-algebra $R$. Is it true that
$$(HK)_a(R) = H(R)K(R) \,?$$

Comment: Is $R$ a finitely generated $K$-algebra?

Comment: @MarkSapir no, since it's arbitrary. (However if it's true for every commutative fg $K$-algebra, it's true for every commutative $K$-algebra, by an easy argument)

Comment: Since $HK =H \times K / (H \cap K)$, the obstruction to doing this should be a class in $H^1 (R, H \cap K)$ which will vanish since $H \cap K$ is unipotent (using here the characteristic zero assumption).

Comment: @WillSawin Sorry if I'm being naive, but wouldn't this apply only when $R$ is a field?

Comment: No, it would just be the etale cohomology or maybe fppf. We have a map $H \times K \to (HK)_a$ which is a map from smooth variety to a smooth variety whose fibers have the same dimension, so it is flat, and $H\cap K$ acts simply transitively on each fiber, so it is an (fppf) $H \cap K$-torsor. The obstruction to finding a section is an fppf cohomology class which vanishes because $(HK)_a$ is affine.